# How much information is there about the Wall of the Faithless and the crusades against it, and where can I find it?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms

I'm getting ready to DM a Forgotten Realms campaign against the Wall, but I'm not sure if I have all the information I could have.

This will be a sequel to the last campaign we had, where one of the characters managed to get most of the others interested in joining him in a crusade as soon as the preparations are complete; the player in question got the idea after playing a game called Mask of the Betrayer.

Now, I haven't played this game but plan on watching a playthrough of it, but I'm wondering if there's any more information in a book or a supplement or something that I could read; the more info I have on it the better prepared I'll be.

This will be a D&D 3.5e campaign, so anything specific to 4e or later won't be of use to me. Aside from that, though, anything you could find will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why are the Faithless condemned to the Wall of the Faithless after death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62456/why-are-the-faithless-condemned-to-the-wall-of-the-faithless-after-death)

Comment: @Raj very nice read. I wish it was available back when I asked this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links about the Wall of the Faithless:
[NWN2 Wiki](http://nwn2.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Faithless) and [FR Wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Faithless)

I've read a lot of game books and novels set in the FR, but not much is mentioned about the WotF. The only place where it plays a major role is the game expansion [Neverwinter Nights 2: Mask of the Betrayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights_2%3a_Mask_of_the_Betrayer)

Comment: Yeah, I guess they didn't elaborate much on it until MoB. I'm surprised, though, since it's a pretty controversial issue.