# Can unbelieving characters be resurrected in 4e Forgotten Realms

Tags: dnd-4e, forgotten-realms

After some research about the [Wall of the Faithless](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/how-much-information-is-there-about-the-wall-of-the-faithless-and-the-crusades-a), it seems that it's gone from Forgotten Realms in the 4e. So where do the souls of the unbelievers go now?

The 3e Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting says that the souls of unbelievers go into the Wall of the Faithless and can't be resurrected. So in 3e your character had to have a patron deity in order to be resurrected. His/her soul went to the Fugue Plane and then to the realm of his patron deity.

Now the souls go to the Shadowfell (ex Plane of Shadow) and Kelemvor still judges them. But where do the souls go after the judgement if they had no patron deity in life? And most importantly, can they be resurrected?

I'm asking this from a "lore point of view", because it seems that the 4e Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting book focuses more on new rules and doesn't change the default rules like the 3e version did.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but 4e is very rules based on there is not restriction on the resurrection, but I assume you are asking from a lore POV. Can you clarify that in your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Discussion from 2010 suggests the wall is still there, and unbelievers are on a timer before they're cemented into the wall of the faithless.**

[Quoth](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25791453/Wall_of_the_Faithless&post_num=4#465106853):

> It's still there until they specifically say it's not.  We've been told to assume that unless something is described as different or gone, then it's still there.

[Details of the wall](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25791453/Wall_of_the_Faithless&post_num=11#465415121):

> Some minimal amount of real worship is required to initiate a patron relationship with a god.  Without a patron, no god can claim you, so you are stuck in the Fugue.  The servitors of any god who is not your patron cannot even see you, speak to you or interact with you in anyway. After a time, if no god comes to collect you, you feel the siren tug of Kelemvor's city calling to you to come for judgment.
>
> The faithless begin to petrify and are tossed onto the wall.  There is a moss that acts like a mortar that is corrosive and breaks down the substance of the petitioner body.  Eventually the petitioner body is eaten away.

Moreover, there seems to be [discussion of](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25791453/Wall_of_the_Faithless&post_num=7#465141569) discussion of the wall in 4e fiction:

> The wall was also mentioned in 4e novels (Edge of Chaos briefly mentions it IIRC)

On the other hand, heroes of shadow has worked out the Keeper of the Everflow ED. While the Heroes of X books are certainly not FR, the wall of the faithless can trivially equate to the raven queen stealing souls for her afterlife and Keepers can exist trying to restore the "natural" order of things.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, as a matter of fact, as the 3E edition of the FRCS states:

> Of more concern to most adventurers, **a character who dies without a
>   patron deity cannot be raised from the dead by any mortal means short
>   of a miracle or wish.** When such a character dies, he is considered one
>   of the Faithless, and his soul is used to form part of the wall around
>   the realm of Kelemvor, god of the dead. Mortal action cannot reverse
>   this fate, and so unless the character's friends can arrange direct
>   intervention by another deity (or expend a mira- cle or wish, spells
>   symbolizing intervention by another deity), that character is unlikely
>   to return to life. (See the Cosmology section of Chapter 5: Deities
>   for more information.)

Comment: It's a 4E question.

Comment: @HeyICanChan But wouldn't the 3E FRCS be equally valid as a source?

Comment: No. A bigger Realms fan than I can tell you more, but apparently Wizards (and, perhaps, *wizards*) exploded the Forgotten Realms again for 4th edition.